# Error when running dockerfile-rails gem: undefined method `load_file' for JSON:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dockerfile

I'm using this Ruby on Rails gem called [dockerfile-rails](https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails) to try and generate a dockerfile in my app, but it just throws an error adds an empty Dockerfile to my root directory:

I ran the command `bundle add dockerfile-rails --optimistic --group development` as described on their docs and I can see `gem "dockerfile-rails", ">= 1.5", :group => :development` in the Gemfile, but when I try to run `bin/rails generate dockerfile` I get an error in the terminal:

```
block in api_client_dir': undefined method 'load_file' for JSON:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I'm using ruby -v `2.7.2p137` and Rails -v `7.0.6`.

Comment: Could you provide more details such a stacktrace and exact version of dockerfile-rails? I've checked the same you do on Ruby 2.7.5 and Rails 7.0.6 - it works as expected.

Comment: Hm. I discovered a bit more a I was lucky to reproduce the same error. It happens here because your Gemfile has `vite-ruby` gem: https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails/blob/520a8fbdcc982df5f35a988555a6114eb119b2df/lib/generators/dockerfile_generator.rb#L295

Comment: So it looks clear for now. `JSON.load_file` does not exist in Ruby 2.7 stdlib. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html but it is in Ruby 3.x: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load_file

Comment: Gem `dockerfilerails` states that minimal version of Ruby could be 2.6.0: https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails/blob/main/dockerfile-rails.gemspec#L22 but has no CI config for versions other than 3.2: https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L10 
So it's a bug in a gem. Though it is probably possible to fix it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in [dockerfile-rails](https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails) gem. There are several solutions for that:

1. Update your Ruby version up to >= 3.0 - the problem won't happen on this version.
2. Report an issue to [dockerfile-rails](https://github.com/fly-apps/dockerfile-rails), wait for fix.
3. Apply reasonable patch to JSON module as follow:

```rb
module JSON
  module_function
  def load_file(filespec, opts = {})
    parse(File.read(filespec), opts)
  end
end
```

somewhere before dockerfile-rails is loaded.

4. Comment or remove `vite-ruby` from your Gemfile, generate Dockerfile, then uncomment `vite ruby`.